# Oracle SQL case condition involving one column but changing another

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm trying to change the sortest_tesc_code of any tuple whose sortest_test_date is greater than 5 years to ZZZ

```
select sortest_pidm, sortest_tesc_code 
     case sortest_tesc_code 
     when extract(year from sysdate)-extract(year from sortest_test_date)>=5 then 'ZZZ' 
          else sortest_tesc_code end as sortest_tesc_code
from tempTbl2
```

assuming tempTbl2 (derived) is this:

[image]

Sample data:

```
MOD7    1   10-JAN-11
MOD9    1   10-JAN-11
MPA3    1   19-JUL-11
C012    3   01-JUL-18
C030    3   01-JUL-17
MPA2    1   12-JUL-18
```

Change to:

```
ZZZ     1   10-JAN-11
ZZZ     1   10-JAN-11
ZZZ     1   19-JUL-11
C012    3   01-JUL-18
C030    3   01-JUL-17
MPA2    1   12-JUL-18
```

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results as formatted text, not images. Apart from having `case sortest_tesc_code` instead of just `case` (so you're mixing simple and searched forms), and an odd way of determining 5 years (months_between/12 might be better?) - what is the issue with your current statement?

Comment: I'm trying to reorganize the sortest_tesc_code to change to ZZZ whenever the sortest_tesc_score is more than 5 years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You merely got a little confused with the `CASE` syntax.

```
select
   case when extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from sortest_test_date) >= 5 
     then 'ZZZ' 
     else sortest_tesc_code
  end as new_sortest_tesc_code,
  testscore,
  sortest_test_date
from tempTbl2
order by sortest_test_date, sortest_tesc_code;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the simple and searched case expression syntax; and your calculation of 'five years' is a bit odd - I would base it on months between the two dates, not just look at the year numbers:

```
with tempTbl2(sortest_tesc_code, testscore, sortest_test_date) as (
  select 'MOD7', 1, date '2011-01-10' from dual union all
  select 'MOD9', 1, date '2011-01-10' from dual union all
  select 'MPA3', 1, date '2011-07-19' from dual union all
  select 'C012', 3, date '2018-07-01' from dual union all
  select 'C030', 3, date '2017-07-01' from dual union all
  select 'MPA2', 1, date '2018-07-12' from dual
)
select
  case
    when add_months(sysdate, -60) > sortest_test_date then 'ZZZ' 
    else sortest_tesc_code
  end as sortest_tesc_code,
  testscore,
  sortest_test_date
from tempTbl2
```

| SORTEST_TESC_CODE | TESTSCORE | SORTEST_TEST_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ZZZ | 1 | 10-JAN-11 |
| ZZZ | 1 | 10-JAN-11 |
| ZZZ | 1 | 19-JUL-11 |
| C012 | 3 | 01-JUL-18 |
| C030 | 3 | 01-JUL-17 |
| MPA2 | 1 | 12-JUL-18 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ed9fc7332bb1427cd45fbfe73798e45)

---

Using `extract(year from sysdate)-extract(year from sortest_test_date)>=`, any date before 2018-01-01 will match; treating a date that is, as of today, only 4 years and 42 days ago as more than 5 years ago seems wrong to me. Perhaps you have a legitimate reason to do that, of course, in which case just change the condition back to what you had.